# Pandas Multi Index and Dash DataTable : How to separate the same index?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

Data :

```
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash

row_data={('id', '', ''): {0: 984, 1: 985, 2: 986, 3: 987, 4: 988},
 ('email', '', ''): {0: 'aa@gmail.com',1: 'bb@gmail.com',2: 'bb@gmail.com',3: 'cc@gmail.com',4: 'ff@dada.com'},
 ('feedback', 'AAA', 'Zaza'): {0: 'Perfect', 1: 'Loose',2: 'nan',3: 'nan',4: 'nan'},
 ('feedback', 'AAA', 'Kuku'): {0: 'Perfect',1: 'Tight',2: 'nan',3: 'nan',4: 'nan'},
 ('feedback', 'AAA', 'Duku'): {0: 'Tight',1: 'Perfect',2: 'nan',3: 'nan',4: 'nan'},
 ('feedback', 'AAA', 'Sasa'): {0: 'Tight',1: 'Perfect',2: 'nan',3: 'nan',4: 'nan'},
 ('feedback', 'AAA', 'Rere'): {0: 'Perfect',1: 'nan',2: 'nan',3: 'nan',4: 'nan'},
 ('results', 'AAA', 'Zaza'): {0: 14, 1: 12,2: 74,3: 87,4: 65},
 ('results', 'AAA', 'Kuku'): {0: 20, 1: 'nan', 2: 45, 3: 52, 4: 71},
 ('results', 'AAA', 'Duku'): {0: 25,1: 78,2: 25,3: 46,4: 89},
 ('results', 'AAA', 'Sasa'): {0: 45,1: 91,2: 45,3: 87, 4: 85},
 ('results', 'AAA', 'Rere'): {0: 42,  1: 77,  2: 45,  3: 12, 4: 41}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row_data)
columns = [{"name": col, "id": "_".join(col)} for col in df.columns]
data = [ {"_".join(col): val for col, val in row.items() } for row in df.to_dict('records')]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    columns=columns,
    data=data,
    merge_duplicate_headers=True,
    style_cell={'textAlign': 'center'},
            css=[
            {'selector': 'th[data-dash-column^="id"]', 'rule': 'background-color: gray'},
            {'selector': 'th[data-dash-column^="email"]', 'rule': 'background-color: gray'},

            {'selector': 'th[data-dash-column^="results"]', 'rule': 'background-color: #3d69e1'},
            {'selector': 'th[data-dash-column^="feedback"]', 'rule': 'background-color: #849feb'},
            {'selector': 'th[data-dash-column^=""]', 'rule': 'background-color: #c0d1ff'}

        ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Pandas Output :
[image]

Dash DataTable Output:
[image]

As you can see in the Dash DataTable, a second-level header will merge together. I can not remove this level because in the future more categories will be added at this level.
I think the one way is to add something to the Pandas this level index,  but I can't figure out how to do it.

Target Output in Dash:
[image]

This means that a second-level title will be under each first-level title.

Answer (score -2):

use [dash_tabulator](https://github.com/preftech/dash-tabulator) and read http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/columns#groups

the documentation for dash_tabulator is incomplete. I was able to figure out multi-index columns from the second link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31850851)